# TeXworks Edit Preferences shows numbers in written Arabic instead of English numerals

Tags: texworks

I'm new to LaTeX and recently started using TeXworks on a Linux Mint 18.3 computer. I needed to edit the preferences and to my surprise discovered that numbers are in written Arabic rather than numerals (see the two uploaded files). How can this be fixed?

[image: Screenshot 1a]

[image: Screenshot 2a]

Please see the two further screenshots - I hope they mean something to you.  In addition, FYI my location is Abu Dhabi UAE, could[image: Screenshot 4] this could be the source of the problem?

I cannot continue right now, but will look in again tomorrow.

[image: Screenshot 5]

A few minutes ago I tried the following using the terminal, changed LC_NUMERIC to have en_US.UTF-8 as the language:
[image: Screenshot 6]

This gave me:

[image: Screenshot 7]

So I then started TeXworks and looked at the Preferences, but there was no change, so I perofrmed a Restart thinking this was correct.  There was still no effect.

Is it possible that I can "force" the locale settings to become "fixed" so that they cannot be altered?  Please advise this frustrated novice.  Thanks

Comment: In the General tab, what does it show for the Locale?

Comment: For Locale it shows "System default (English)"  does this help you to help me?  If you tell me how to do it, I will upload another screenshot (if it helps).

Comment: I have just worked out how to return to edit my original question and upload an additional screenshot - I hope this helps

Comment: The measurement seems to be set as arabic, don't know if texworks grabs this set insteat of numerals?

Comment: I think it's picking up the `LC_NUMERIC` setting.

Comment: Try changing the Locale setting to just English. The system default is likely picking up the language name from `LANG` or `LANGUAGE`, but using the other environment variables according to the GUI element type.

Comment: I'm happy to take your word for this explanation, can you advise me as how to fix it?

Comment: A few minutes ago I tried the following (see image)